# Can a friend function access member variables without creating any object

Tags: c++

An inherited class can access member variables without using .(dot) operator. Can we also access the member variables in friend class without using the dot operator with object name. If not, why?

```
void show();

class Test{
 int a;
 friend void show();
}

void show(){
 cout<<a; //why this is not possible
}

int main(){
 show();
}
```

Comment: Because class is just a structure. It doesn't exist in memory until you initialize an object.

Comment: A derived class member function has an implicit `this`. The "dot" or "arrow" are still there, just invisible. A friend function is not a member.

Comment: Thanks both of you, you made my thinking refined.

Comment: You can't because `a` is a member of a data structure.   It is necessary for an instance of that data structure to exist in order to access its members.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such a thing. When you have a member function, even inside an inherited class, the compiler implicitly had to the function an implicit `this` argument, and even as you don't write it yourself, it is their.
A friend function on the other hand is not a part of the class, and therefore it doesn't have an access to it.

Also logically, without an object of the class, you don't have any memory which will contain the member, and therefore you can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use a member variables without create object of the class. 
way1: static variable

```
void show();

class Test {
    static int a;
    friend void show();
};
int Test::a;
void show() {

    cout << Test::a; 
}

int main() {
    show();
}
```

way2:send in argument of show function get reference to object of class Test

```
void show();

class Test {
    int a;
    friend void show(Test* test);
};

void show(Test* test) {
    cout << test->a; 
}

int main() {
    show(new Test);
}
```

You can find out:

> The friend declaration appears in a class body and grants a function or another class access to private and protected members of the class where the friend declaration appears.